# What is the appropriate procedure for having an app remember details in a textfield, within a static table, within UITableViewController? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have a UITableViewController on a personal details screen which holds a table of static cells which holds textfields. The user will enter the necessary information into these textfields and press a save button. Ideally once saved the personal details will remain within the textfields after closing the app.
I would appreciate it if someone could clarify the necessary steps to have this work.
I am using Xcode & Swift.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSUserDefaults`:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

Save:

```
defaults.setObject("Some String", forKey: "someKey")
```

Read:

```
if let someString = defaults.stringForKey("someKey") {
    print(someString)
}
```

Source of information and for further reading:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/
- http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/

Answer (score 0):

The Model-View-Controller principle states that your views (such as textfields, tableviews etc.) only represent data stored in a model, and don't hold data themselves.

Your approach should be:

1. The tableview/textfield shows data as stored in the model (empty to begin with)
2. When the user enters details and taps 'save', you synchronize the model and view by saving data to the model. You should probably use CoreData, although `NSUserDefaults` would be a quick and naive way of doing this.
3. On subsequent visits to the view-controller, step 1 will ensure that the views are in sync with the model, and step 2 will ensure that the model synchronises when changes to the model are intended.